# haproxy direct syslog data flow with log-forward

Tags: haproxy

I’ve been working on creating a new syslog setup and have run into an issue, that i cannot find a solution for, so i thought maybe someone here could help me out.

I have a setup with 2 syslog servers and 2 haproxy nodes(in HA with keepalived). i have 2 endpoints on configured on the haproxy nodes: “endpoint_X” and “endpoint_Y” for different types of logs. I would like to control the flow of syslog messages, so that when syslog is send to “endpoint_X”:514 its send to syslog01 and when “endpoint_Y”:514 its send to syslog02. this is normally done with the use of ACL’s for normal frontends. But for syslog I use HAproxy’s “log-forward” function, where ACL’s is not supported for.

Below is an example of my config:

```
ring syslog01
    description " "
    format rfc3164
    maxlen 1200
    size 357913941
    server syslog01 XXXXX_01:514 source YYYYY check
    timeout client 90s
    timeout connect 10s
    timeout server 90s
    timeout check 10s

ring syslog02
    description " "
    format rfc3164
    maxlen 1200
    size 357913941
    server syslog02 XXXXX_02:514 source YYYYYY check
    timeout client 90s
    timeout connect 10s
    timeout server 90s
    timeout check 10s

log-forward syslog
    bind 0.0.0.0:514
    bind [::]:514
    dgram-bind 0.0.0.0:514
    dgram-bind [::]:514
    log ring@syslog01 local0 
    log ring@syslog02 local0
```

does anyone have an idea if there is something i can do to get around this issue , so i can control the data flow in log-forward, other than using differen ports? I use haproxy version 2.6

i have tried some like the following, but as stated ACL does not work with log-forward:

```
acl acl_endpoint_X hdr(host) -i endpoint_X
acl acl_endpoint_X hdr(host) -i endpoint_Y
    
log ring@syslog01 local0 if endpoint_X hdr(host)
log ring@syslog02 local0 if endpoint_Y hdr(host)
```